# Cost of a partial barrel shifter

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, cost

As I understand it, a 32-bit barrel shifter takes about five thousand transistors.

Suppose you built a shifter that is like a barrel shifter in providing an answer instantly without iteration, but only allows shifts in 8-bit increments. How much cheaper with that be in transistor count, gate delays, power consumption? Would it be dramatically cheaper, or just slightly?

(And, what's the right name for that kind of shifter?)

Comment: "A barrel shifter is a digital circuit that can shift a data word by a specified number of bits without the use of any sequential logic, only pure combinatorial logic."

Comment: 5k transistors for a 32-bit barrel shifter? Looks like a lot to me… I’d say 650 at first sight.

Comment: In a 32-bit barrel shifter, each of these 32 input bits can be mapped to 32 different outputs. This means 32x32=1024 data paths. So we have a weight for a data path: about 5 transistors. Ignoring scaling effects, that would mean a partial barrel shifter where each of the 32 bits may only be mapped to 4 different outputs: such a shifter would have 128 data paths and considering the weight of 5, it needed about 500 transistors.

Answer (score 2):

While @Janka's [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301234/cost-of-a-partial-barrel-shifter#comment694341_301234)

> In a 32-bit barrel shifter, each of these 32 input bits can be mapped to 32 different outputs. This means 32x32=1024 data paths. So we have a weight for a data path: about 5 transistors. Ignoring scaling effects, that would mean a partial barrel shifter where each of the 32 bits may only be mapped to 4 different outputs, such a shifter would wave 128 data path and cosiderung the weight of 5, it needed about 500 transistors.

demonstrates the difference in transistor counts, this doesn't say very much about the difference in power consumption or cost.

- How much does a low-power transistor on **your** die cost?
- Does it make a difference at all, if you already have a couple million transistors?
- What's the power consumption of an unused   transistor in your technology?
- How many times will you actually change the data word or the shift?
- how many times will you use the individual shifts in relation to each other? Will a 24 bit shift be as common as a 1 bit shift (my guess: no!)?
- Will having the full barrel shifter save energy somewhere else (e.g. a multiplier)?

So, up- and downside of any semiconductor design decision will depend on the tech you use!

What we, indeed, can say is that if we stay with the 4-of-32-possible-shifters in parallel architecture, the gate delay will be identical, aside from the shift width decode logic (which you didn't specify).

Comment: "How many times will you actually change the data word or the shift?" good question, hadn't thought of this before, suppose you want to do a million shifts with different data words but the same shift amount (then another million with a different shift amount, etc), can you design to take advantage of that and be faster or consume less power than if the shift amount would change every time?

Comment: Probably, but I'd have to think about that very intensely. My point was more that MOS consumes power when switching, not when keeping the fate voltage constant

Comment: I use barrel shifters a lot. In particular, the ADSP-21xx and Blackfin variety. I have two basic uses: (1) use a barrel shifter to normalize a word and count the number of shifts required in 1 clock; and, (2) use a barrel shifter to de-normalize a word given a shift count to use. I use #1 *more often* than I use #2. Granularity above one bit in either case would add many wasted cycles, take longer, consume more power, etc. Not so good. Just an FYI to this discussion.